# installing kubuntu-desktop failed during 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` to `18.04`.
I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade` and after around 1 hour the process finished with:

```
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.79ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kubuntu-desktop
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Could not install the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A 
recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a). 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on software-properties-kde; however:
  Package software-properties-kde is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kubuntu-desktop

Upgrade complete 

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade 
process. 

To continue please press [ENTER]
```

I rebooted and my linux seems to be `18.04`, so I thought it was just the `kubuntu-desktop` install that didn't work. I tried to force install it:

```
sudo apt-get install -f kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-driver-manager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-notification-helper but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In the following I always tried force installing the dependencies that were unmet:
`kubuntu-desktop` -> `software-properties-kde` -> `python3-pyqt5` -> `libpython3.6` -> `libpython3.6-stdlib`
When I tried to install `libpython3.6-stdlib` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpython3.6-stdlib is already the newest version (3.6.7-1+xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Did anyone encounter a similar problem?

Comment: When on 16.04, after you installed `kubuntu-desktop`, did you also use the kubuntu-backports ppa to get updated versions of Plasma, etc. If so,that could be the reason why the upgrade from 16.04 > 18.04 is broken at least with respect to kubuntu-desktop. If you have backed up your personal data, I'd suggest doing a clean install of whatever flavor you want. Mixing two desktop environments *could* be problematic.

Comment: I removed the `python3` tag as it was causing needless syntax highlighting. Please feel free to put it back if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: On 16.04 I never installed `kubuntu-desktop` by hand. I added a few repositories, but only for mongo-db, kdeconnect, R-dev as I remember.

Comment: The situation is that the upgrade process somehow tried to upgrade `kubuntu-desktop` and couldn't do so. The simplest option is to do a clean install. Otherwise, if you are very familiar with `aptitude`, you could use that to deal with broken packages. Right now, it isn't clear what your system permits you to do.

Comment: yeah.. installed new